# Aspose Cells for Excel - Repeat Dynamic Formula for INDEX and MATCH

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match, aspose, aspose-cells

[image]Could you please help?

Sample formula in one cell:

`=INDEX('Customer Concen Customer Master'!$A:$H,MATCH(J2,'Customer Concen Customer Master'!$A$2:$A$295104,0)+1,2)`

Template formula:

`&=&=INDEX('Customer Concen Customer Master'!$A:$H,MATCH(J{r},'Customer Concen Customer Master'!$A$2:$A$295104,0)+1,2)`

We are tring to add this template formula in "Sheet 1" of Excel, this forumla is dependent upon the 
"Customer Concen Customer Master" Excel sheet in same Excel template.

The sample formula is working for one cell, when we try to append `&=&=` and then change `J2` to `J{r}`, its NOT working.
We are getting **"Invalid Formula"** exception.

I think, we can not attach sample files in Stack Oveflow.
So, I attached image. Please find more details about sample expected output

"My Lookup" sheet constains "CustomerNo" in Column A in Excel, "Cons/Hold #" in Column B in Excel
CustomerNo (Column A)       Cons/Hold # (Column B)
21                                aa
22                                bb
23                                cc
24                                dd
25                                ee
26                                ff
27                                gg
28                                hh
29                                ii
30                                jj

"Main Customer" sheet constains "Main Customer Number" in Column A in Excel, "CUSTOMER_NUMBER" in Column J in Excel

Main Customer Number (Column A)     CUSTOMER_NUMBER (Column J)
aa                                         21
bb                                         22
cc                                         23
dd                                         24
ee                                         25
ff                                         26
gg                                         27
hh                                         28
ii                                         29
jj                                         30

Main Customer Number contains this formula in cell A2 in Excel template
=INDEX('My Lookup'!$A:$B,MATCH(J2,'My Lookup'!$A$2:$A$11,0)+1,2)

I am trying to add below formula in C# by accessing Main Customer sheet like this:

mainCustomerWorksheet.Cells["B2"].Formula = "&=&=INDEX('My Lookup'!$A:$B,MATCH(J{r},'My Lookup'!$A$2:$A$11,0)+1,2)";

Please note following changes between sample formla and template formula
1) &=&= is prefixed in template formula
2) J2 is changed to J{r} in template formula
3) I am counting total rows (example 11 rows) in "My Lookup" sheet in C# at runtime and constructing formula in C# code for
$A$11 part in template formula

Comment: Please provide your 1) Smart Marker Template Excel file 2) Actual Output Excel file 3) Expected Excel file. You can create Expected Excel file manually using Microsoft Excel. We will look into your provided three files and investigate your issue and help you out. Thanks for your cooperation in this regard and have a good day. ---- Shakeel Faiz --- Note: I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: Hi Shakeel, I have added screenshot and more details to the post. Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: Please add them to dropbox and share the link here. This will help me to look into this issue more precisely. Thanks.